# Change Dropdown values based on input in textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, drop-down-menu

I try to find a solution, but I can't find it and I am not able to program it by myself. I hope you can help me.

I have 2 elements: A textfield and a drop down menu (select/options).

Based on the birth/year of a person I enter into the textfield, I want to have a related drop down values.

If the person is 0-17 years old, the values in the drop down should bei 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600.
If the person is 18 years old or older, the values in the drop down should bei 300, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500.

Example: If I enter 1978 into the text field, the drop down menu should show the values 300, 500,…
If I enter 2002 into the text field, the drop down menu should show the values 100, 200,…

I hope it is understandable what I am looking for.

I have checked this one:
[Change dropdown value based on Text Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052763/change-dropdown-value-based-on-text-input)

and also this one, which looks also similar to what I need:
[jQuery - Change hidden value based on input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975517/jquery-change-hidden-value-based-on-input-field?rq=1)

But I can't make it.

A jsfiddle would be really cool!

Thank you in advance.

```
 <input name="Year" type="text" value="" />

 <select name="Results">
 <option selected="selected" value="">please choose:</option>
 <option value="300">300.-</option>
 <option value="500">500.-</option>
 <option value="1000">1000.-</option>
 <option value="1500">1500.-</option>
 <option value="2000">2000.-</option>
 <option value="2500">2500.-</option>
 </select>

 <select name="Results">
 <option selected="selected" value="">please choose:</option>
 <option value="100">100.-</option>
 <option value="200">200.-</option>
 <option value="300">300.-</option>
 <option value="400">400.-</option>
 <option value="500">500.-</option>
 <option value="600“>600.-</option>
 </select>
```

Kind regards,
Andy

Comment: You could set an 'onChange' event on the input, check the value with an 'if' and either display one of your two select options or generate the select values dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this by taking advantage of `data-*` attributes and using jQuery to determine which values should be shown based on your selection :

```
<!-- Assumes a valid year is entered -->
<input name="Year" type="text" value="" />

<!-- Notice your possible values data options -->
<select name="Results">
   <option selected="selected" value="">please choose:</option>
   <option value="300" data-under-18="100" data-over-18="300">300.-</option>
   <option value="500" data-under-18="200" data-over-18="500">500.-</option>
   <option value="1000" data-under-18="300" data-over-18="1000">1000.-</option>
   <option value="1500" data-under-18="400" data-over-18="1500">1500.-</option>
   <option value="2000" data-under-18="500" data-over-18="2000">2000.-</option>
   <option value="2500" data-under-18="600" data-over-18="2500">2500.-</option>
 </select>
  <script>
    $(function(){
        // When your year changes...
        $('[name="Year"]').change(function(){
            // Check that the value is a year (assumes 4 digit number)
            if(/^\d{4}/.test($(this).val())){
                // Parse the value
                var year = parseInt($(this).val());
                // Determine the user's age
                var age =  new Date().getFullYear() - year;
                // Use the data attributes to set each value (ignore the first one)
                $('[name="Results"] option:not(:first)').each(function(){
                    var valueToUse = (age >= 18) ? $(this).attr('data-over-18') : $(this).attr('data-under-18');
                    $(this).val(valueToUse).text(valueToUse);
                });
            }                
            else{
              alert('Please enter a year! (any 4-digit number will do)');
              $(this).val('').focus();
            }
        })
    })
  </script>
```

You can [see a complete working example here](http://jsbin.com/vabezi/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Dear Rion, thank you very much. I like this version and after implementation, it works excellent. Now I need to add more persons (the same thing several times). This seems to be quite difficult. I have opened another stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876801/multiple-lines-for-change-dropdown-values-based-on-input-in-textfield

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/erjc0fna/

Basically each option has a class that identifies it as `lessThan18` or `over18`. The ones without classes are available for either case according to what you wrote. On `keyup` for the textbox it then calculates the age and hides/shows the correct options.

Comment: Dear Sbonkosky, thank you very much. It seems that the jsfiddle doesn't work with Safari browser. With Chrome it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After add ids to the input(inputId) and the 2 select(select1 and select2)

```
   <input id="inputId" name="Year" type="text" value="" />

 <select id="select1" name="Results">
 <option selected="selected" value="">please choose:</option>
 <option value="300">300.-</option>
 <option value="500">500.-</option>
 <option value="1000">1000.-</option>
 <option value="1500">1500.-</option>
 <option value="2000">2000.-</option>
 <option value="2500">2500.-</option>
 </select>

 <select id="select2" name="Results">
 <option selected="selected" value="">please choose:</option>
 <option value="100">100.-</option>
 <option value="200">200.-</option>
 <option value="300">300.-</option>
 <option value="400">400.-</option>
 <option value="500">500.-</option>
 <option value="600“>600.-</option>
 </select>
```

Code jquery

```
<script>
//here the code
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#inputId").keypress(function(e) 
    {
        if(e.which == 13) //When you press enter key one select is hide an the other is show
        {
            var aux =  parseInt($(this).val());
            if( aux >= 1999)
            {
                $("#select2").show();
                $("#select1").hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#select1").show();
                $("#select2").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
<script>
```

Comment: Dear Satellite, thank you very much for giving this support.